# Using ADB to set creating by myself launcher as default

Tags: android

Is it possible to set launcher as default (This is my launcher and I have .apk) using adb? I must set same launcher on 20 devices. I can't install root.

Comment: Install apk to your device (no need of root, you can copy apk file to your phone then select it from file manager of your phone. The installer will install your app).  After installation select home button and android popups dialog where should be shown your launcher and android launcher. Choose your launcher as default

Comment: I know this way but I want to use ADB same as I install apks on multiple devices

Comment: you can try "adb install"

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator